# Equivalent of =SUM(ABOVE) in numbers?

Tags: ms-office, numbers

I have a table like this,

[image]

I need to sum all fields above (exclude the header), the following formula works:

```
=SUM(C1:C5)
```

When I add more rows I must rewrite the formula, then I tried something like this:

```
=SUM(C)
```

Because there's a header in column C, SUM function failed as expected.

What should I use? Number does not support `=SUM(ABOVE)` and MS Excel is as stuck as it can be.

Comment: You said, "When I add more rows I must rewrite the formula", where are you adding the rows, before the cell that has the formula or after? If before, the formula should automatically update. If after, and I were doing it, I'd remove the formula, reselect the cells to sum and then click Insert > Formula > Sum or drag and drop the (SUM n) from the bottom of the window and place it in whatever cell you want.  If I'd also use SUM often enough then I'd gave it a keyboard shortcut (^S) in: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, I'm adding rows after the last row, so that's the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When putting a sum-over-the-entire-column formula into a regular cell, you are basically self-referencing the formula cell as a value cell.

Try putting the the formula into a footer row. This way you can reference only the cells in a column without including the header or footer row.

1. Add a footer row in the "Header & Footer" section in the Format > Table sidebar

[image: Numbers Table Footer Setup]

2. Put the SUM formula in the footer row (the last row in the image below) and select the entire column by referencing the column letter or the column header title (column header title here is "Header" :).

(Select footer cell, type "=SUM", press Enter, type header title or column letter, press Enter)

[image: Numbers SUM formula footer row]

As shown, only the cells, without the header or footer row, are selected. The sum is calculated over all cells in the column, even when adding new rows.

Comment: Yes, this one excludes the header automatically

Answer (score 2):

SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN(),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()−1,COLUMN(),4), 1))
Where 2 is the first row after headers to be summed

Comment: I don’t know about OP but this did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using version 5.1 (5683), to my (limited) knowledge of **Numbers**, there is not an equivalent of the **Excel** `=SUM(ABOVE)` *formula* in **Numbers**.

If you primarily want to use the keyboard, start by adding a *keyboard shortcut* for the **SUM** *formula* in **Numbers** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts** as shown in the image further below.

I gave it: **^S**

Now, in **Numbers**, you can *sum* any *column* above the selected *cell* by pressing: **^S**

If you then need to extend the number of *cells* beyond the *cell* that has the **SUM** *formula*, simple do the following:

1. Select the *cell* that contains the **SUM** *formula* and press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.
2. Fill in the *values* of the empty *cells* as needed.
3. Press: **^S**

You now have a new *sum* for all *cells* above the selected *cell* you want the **SUM** *formula* in.

---

[image: App Keyboard Shortcut]

<sub>**The shortcut is: Control-S**</sub>

Answer (score -2):

You can define your expression by writing = sum( and then clicking with your cursor on the first row you want to include and then dragging the cursor down to the last row. This is much simpler than writing the values in.

Below is an image of a sum expression.

[image]

The only thing I actually typed was the characters = sum(. After using the cursor to select B2 thru B11 I typed the closing ).

Comment: For **SUM**, you really do not need to first write anything, simply select the cell you want the formula in and click Insert > Formula > Sum

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: no, you write in the cell you want the total to appear. you write "=sum(" without the quotes. Then put the cursor in 1st cell which you want to include and just pull the cursor down to last cell.

Comment: I didn't down vote.

Comment: yea i didn't think it was you...

Comment: the only thing you have to type, one time, is = sum(.

Comment: @user3439894 I editted my answer and included an image of a numbers spreadsheet and the selection of the rows.

Comment: Not sure why you're bring your edit to my attention. 1. I didn't down vote your answer. 2. To me, your edit doesn't make your answer any better in light of the fact one does not need to type anything, as you can simply select a cell in the same column that you want to sum and click Insert > Formula > Sum and no typing necessary.  You can also select the cells you want to sum and then drag and drop the (SUM n) from the bottom of the window and place it in whatever cell you want. Again, no typing necessary, and as one would already have their hand on the mouse why not just use the mouse.

Comment: I was just trying to clarify my answer. if it didn't help I apologize. I was just trying to help. I know you didn't downvote my answer but I was afraid it wasn't clear so I edited my answer. If you have found a better solution that's a good thing.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. Fixed range of rows to sum up. When more rows like B12, B13 is added, you will need to edit the formula to reflect the changes. In excel `sum(above)` can dynamically select all rows above, excluding the header